# why splash screen or launch screen image of flutter app is not being shown in high quality

Tags: android, flutter, splash-screen, launch-screen

In my flutter app i have set a *.PNG image as splash screen or starup screen to be shown when this app starts but **it is not being shown in high quality** and i have tried to set another high quality image then image spreads outside of the screen (kind of over zoomed) but i have seen many app's flash screen is in good quality, i have seen [Splash Screen logo displayed is of poor quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51134538/splash-screen-logo-displayed-is-of-poor-quality) i am seeking if there is another easy way to do so please let me know thanks

**Things i am using (Flutter, on vscode, for android, on windows 10)**

Comment: You have mentioned you saw that solution in other question. What is the problem with it then?

Comment: is there any other easy way?

Comment: Use vector image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a static `png` file will almost always give you such problems. You need to consider different screen sizes and dpi for different devices. If you still want to use your own `png` convert it into `svg` with this site https://picsvg.com/ and convert it into material usable icon with this site https://android-material-icon-generator.bitdroid.de/. It is easy and will save you much effort.