# Android Studio Vector Assets - How to merge/combine two vector assets together?

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm currently designing some ImageButtons to be drawn on top of a map, and one of them is supposed to bring up a list of currently favourited markers that would be permanently displayed on the map.
Apart from holding down the custom InfoWindow, a marker can be added to this list from a separate activity by clicking a button on the that activity's action bar, which for its icon uses the android vector asset named [star_border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltra6.png).
Now, as the ImageButton's src, I would like to use a combination of the [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IN6tU.png) vector asset and the star, which would sort of be in the bottom right, like a subscript.
Can this be done by editing together XML code, or do I use a third party program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the [`<layer-list />`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList). With it you can stack multiple drawable. But scaling and centering is a pain on its [own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34831142/how-to-center-vector-drawable-in-layer-list-without-scaling).

Comment: Although I moved onto a different project, thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 3):

Create XML file under Drawable and put your SVG images as like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_first"
    android:gravity="center"/>

  <item
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_second"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</layer-list>
```