# Android Studio Vector Asset Tool Content not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

I am trying to create a splash screen for one of my apps with it's logo and my companies logo on it. To make sure I get no resizing problems I wanted to use SVG files and create a vector asset using the Android Studios built in tool.

However when I want to create an asset using *New > Vector Asset* and then *Local File* and provide the path to my SVG file I get following error: `Error while parsing logo.svg: Content is not allowed in prolog.`.

I created my SVG file using Paint and my logos PNG file. I simply saved the file as SVG in the same path with the same name. I saved both files PNG and SVG in the *drawable* folder.

Any help is much appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.

Opening a PNG file in Paint and simply exporting it as SVG does not do the trick.
I asked my graphic designer to convert the PNG files to SVG and then I was able to use the built in tool to create a vector asset with no effort.