# Android drawable - how to create a cross on top right corner of another drawable

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, drawable

I need to create following design as a drawable, to set it as a background of a button.

[Button design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAgxg.png)

I have already created a [drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOBhQ.png) with green background and rounded corners, I also have a [drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81pJf.png) which is oval with white border, orange background and a white X, but I have no idea how to "put it" on the right top corner of another drawable.

The only result which I've got is this:

[Final drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOAy5.png)

Which is absolutely not what I'm searching for. It looks like this in app:

[Design in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cV92.png)

I would appreciate any help, thank you! I'm desperate.

---

**SOLUTION:**

Thanks to [Bö macht Blau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/b%C3%B6-macht-blau)  and [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) I was able to solve the problem.

Here is a final drawable:

[Final drawable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNfNy.png)

And the drawable code is:

**raw_material_button.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/green_button_rounded"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:left="10dp" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/close_raw_material"
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp"
        android:gravity="end"/>
</layer-list>
```

**green_button_rounded.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```

**close_raw_material.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false"
        >
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
            <padding android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="1dp"
        android:left="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/textYellow" />

        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="135"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="135">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:right="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="45"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="45">
            <shape android:shape="line">
                <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/white" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Maybe [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58923310/5015207) is helpful

Comment: Once you get each drawable individually working as you want, a `LayerListDrawable` would let you stack them.

Comment: Combination of your answers helped me to solve the problem, thanks!